# Reset counter variable on condition

Tags: javascript

I have this simple "pagination" counter which is fetching the next page from an API. It works fine but the problem is that whenever I change category (movies or series) the counter obviously doesn't reset so instead of fetching the first page of the new category it continues from the number it left off.

I tried numerous conditional combinations but nothing really worked so far. I'm sure it's not that hard to solve I just can't think of the right logic to use.

```
let page = 1; 
document.getElementById('load-more').addEventListener('click', () => {
    page++;

    const movies = document.getElementById('movies');
    const series = document.getElementById('series');


    if(movies.classList.contains('active-link')) {

        getMovies(page);


    } else if (series.classList.contains('active-link')) {

        getSeries(page);

    }
})
```

Reseting the let counter inside the if..else doesn't really work because every time I click the load more button it resets it back to page 1.

Comment: Why dont you just use two counters? One for movies and one for series.

Comment: where do you change category ? show me that code.

Comment: You could just save the last fetched category in a variable and reset the counter to zero if the prev category does not match the current clicks category. But that comes donw to the same as all answers below. Just use a second variable somehow to keep track of state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use separate variables for the current movies page and the current series page. Also note that you can simplify your logic by using a single `querySelector` instead of selections followed by `classList.contains`:

```
let moviesPage = 1;
let seriesPage = 1;
document.getElementById('load-more').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (document.querySelector('#movies.active-link')) {
    moviesPage++;
    getMovies(moviesPage);
  } else if (document.querySelector('#series.active-link')) {
    seriesPage++;
    getSeries(seriesPage);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your logic is sound! I didn't think of using two counters! Thank you. But I think your answer was half correct ( maybe it was my mistake because I didn't clearly stated that I wanted to be able to reset the counter). Anyway I used your answer in combination with Pac0 below to reset the counter every time i click on a link

Answer (score 2):

Set another event listener for the click on your #movies and  #series link,

and set the `page` variable to 1 at this place.

That would be the usual behavior when switching lists, one usually see a reset of paging.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped with reseting the counter each time!